# Importing Data Through PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I have a simple csv file

```
1,2,3,6/23/2011 7:40,KNOWS NOT MUCH,4,5
2,3,4,6/23/2011 7:40,FOO BAR BAZ, 6, 7
```

I have copied this on hdfs and I have written this program

```
grunt> A = LOAD '/staging/foo.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (A : int, B : INT, C: INT, D: DATETIME, E: CHARARRAY, F : INT, G : INT);
grunt> DUMP A;
```

The output is

```
Total input paths to process : 1
(1,2,3,,KNOWS NOT MUCH,4,5)
(2,3,4,,FOO BAR BAZ,6,7)
```

What happened to the date part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input `6/23/2011 7:40` is not supported in `datetime format`, so pig will skip this date part during load. To solve this issue, just declare the date `column D` as `chararray` and convert to any of the below format as you need.

Refer the supported datetime format:
https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/func.html#datetime-functions
http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime